# Monitor cpu usage of multiple processes in Python

Tags: python, linux

Is there any way to monitor cpu usage of Linux processes in Python. I tried to import "psutil", but for using function `process.cpu_percent()` you have to set interval as argument and it is not possible when I want info about multiple processes because it will take a lot of time.

If you set argument as `interval=None` it returns value 0.0

Example of code:

```
for pid in PIDs:
   p = psutil.Process(pid)
   print(p.cpu_percent(1))
```

If you have 1000 processes, it will take 1000 seconds and I need to have it immediately.

Comment: Have you tried calling it a second time as its documentation says?

Comment: If it is meant to use print(p.cpu_percent(interval=None)) twice in a row, it will also return 0.0

Comment: "in a row" doesn't sound like you're doing it as instructed.

Comment: Yeah, now I understand what you thought. But when I use sleep(0.1) between calls, it takes 100s for 1000 processes. And that is too much.

Comment: Why does it take that long? Call `cpu_percent()` on all processes, then wait 0.1 seconds, then call `cpu_percent()` on all processes again. Should take a bit more than 0.1 seconds, no?

Comment: Hmm it make sense so I have to create array of "psutil.Process(pid)" but it will not be a problem as if it were borne at all...thanks